# Record fullscreen program with avconv/ffmpeg?

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, ffmpeg, avconv

I'm trying to record a fullscreen program (`snes9x`) with avconv, aka ffmpeg. I have avconv set up to use my whole screen, but it doesn't capture snes9x when I run it.

```
#!/bin/bash
avconv \
  -f x11grab \
  -s 1920x1080 \
  -r 30 \
  -i :0.0 \
  -an \
  -c:v libx264 \
  -preset veryfast \
  -pix_fmt yuv420p \
  -threads 2 \
  -b:v 1M \
  -f flv \
  'rtmp://<ip>/live/<stream name>'
```

How can I modify this script to capture a fullscreen window? I've tried using a Xephyr window to make snes9x itself windowed, but that didn't work (snes9x launched fullscreen anyway).